# Is there a formula/name for the sum of all possible products of $i$ distinct terms in the first $k$ integers?

Tags: co.combinatorics

I'm calculating

$$\prod _{i=1} ^k\big( n(n-1)-2i \big)$$

for $n$ fixed, and I would like to express it as a sum, using a kind of Newton's formula. The problem is, the coefficients are a bit more complicated than the binomial ones, there is the $-2$ that is always there, but $i$ changes, so that I would need to be able to calculate each time the sum of all the possible products of $i$ distinct terms in $1,2, \dots, k$.

For example, for $k=4$, I would have :

$$\begin{eqnarray}
i=1 &:& \quad 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 &=& 10 \\
i=2 &:& \quad 1 \cdot 2 + 1 \cdot 3 + 1 \cdot 4 + 2 \cdot 3 + 2 \cdot 4 + 3 \cdot 4 &=& 35 \\
i=3 &:& \quad 1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 + 1 \cdot 2 \cdot 4 + 1 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 + 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4  &=& 50 \\
i=4 &:& \quad 1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 &=& 24
\end{eqnarray}$$

Is there a known formula, or at least a name, for those kind of coefficients? Thank you in advance and sorry if it's not clear.

Comment: You can calculate your product directly: it equals $2^k\left(\binom{n}{2}-1\right)!/\left(\binom{n}{2}-k-1\right)!$.

Comment: @GHfromMO I wanted to express it as a sum because it was allowing me to cancel other terms of my formula but I think this expression is actually better, it's more understandable. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Your $10,35,50,24$ are Stirling numbers of the first kind. See http://oeis.org/A094638 or http://oeis.org/A008276 or http://oeis.org/A054654

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you, that's exactly what I needed !

Comment: Welcome to mathOverflow!  By the way, whenever I encounter any integer sequence, the first thing I do is type it into oeis.org.  That tells me more about the thing roughly 90% of the time (and when the thing isn't in there, I'll add an entry about it!).  That's a good resource to have in your back pocket.

Answer (score 1):

They are the absolute value of [Stirling numbers of the $1^{st}$ kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingNumberoftheFirstKind.html), wihch are given at OEIS in [A008275](https://oeis.org/A008275).

The unsigned version is [A094638](https://oeis.org/A094638).

A recurrence formula is: $$a_{n,k}=a_{n-1,k-1}+(n-1)a_{n-1,k}$$

As they are the coefficients of $x^k$ in:

$$\prod_\limits{i=1}^n (x+i)$$

letting $x=1$ means the coefficients sum to $(n+1)!$.

Comment: happy to help :)